# Silverlight clipping inside grid

Tags: .net, silverlight

I have a `Grid` and I'd like to apply a `Clip`( I provide `Path` `Data` ) to anything that is inside the `Grid`. For e.g., if I have an image inside the grid, I need the image to be clipped to a custom shape. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the `Clip` property on the `Grid` to the geometry that you want to clip to. Alternatively, there is an attached behaviour described in the following blog post:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/05/silverlight-cliptobounds-can-i-clip-it-yes-you-can/

That can be used as follows:

```
<Grid util:Clip.ToBounds="true">
```

Comment: no, thats not it. I want what is inside the Grid to be clipped to a shape. For e.g., a rectangular image inside the grid, should be clipped to a circle, still inside the grid. The image is completely inside the grid. And I want it to be clipped to another shape also completely inside the grid

Comment: @Aks: I think your question focuses heavily on the presence of a Grid but its leaving us wondering why that is relevent.  Why are you not simply assigning your path to the Image's `Clip` property?

Comment: something like this... http://www.designforquality.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/clipping_path_004.jpg, sorry about the terrible example...only thing i could find on google images

Comment: @Anthony: So, what I'm doing is, I'm translating my image into the grid's viewable area through a storyboard, and as the image enters the grid, it has to look like the image is filling the clipping area. I hope that makes sense

Comment: @aks: How are you doing the translation?  With a rendertransform?  Is it ever actually a child of the Grid.

Comment: yes. rendertransform. It is a child. For simplicity, you can assume my grid has a rectangle of 0 height and i use a storyboard to set its height to maxvalue. And this should appear like the clipping area is being filled bottom up